# TS2345 even on impossible paths

Tags: typescript

```
export interface MyDoc{
  field: string;
}

function insert(doc: MyDoc) { /* db insert code here */ }

let x; // simulate undefined value
let doc = { field: x };

console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
if (x === undefined) { // also does not prevent with doc.field === undefined
  return; // return if x is undefined
}

insert(doc); // causes TS2345: Argument of type error
```

As far as I'm concerned this is not possible, but feels like code smell. How can I inform TS type-checker to `doc` cannot contain `field` with `undefined` in value even tho it is possible to have it for other purposes(like logging)

Comment: What is the exact error? You are not defining a type for `x` in your snippet. So even if `x !== undefined` there is no guarantee whatsoever, that `doc.field` will be a `string` and thus be assignable to a variable of type `MyDoc`. If it's just about the error being in unreachable part of your code: static code analysis has it's limits (an doesn't evaluate the value of `let` variables for control flows) And even if TS would detect unreachable code (which it seemingly doesn't) this code must be syntactically correct and typesafe

Comment: Checking against `x` doesn't work because `doc.field` and `x` are not actually related. Checking against `doc.field` does narrow `doc.field` to `string` (assuming `x` was typed as `string | undefined`, but for some reason does not narrow `doc` from ` { field: string | undefined }` to `{ field: string }` (e.g. by intersecting the type of `doc` and the type `{ field: string }`.

Comment: See this TS playground for ideas: https://dub.sh/trUQnRL

Comment: This is a limitation of TS; only certain type guards have effects on a value other than the one guarded, and you're not using one of those type guards. (See [ms/TS#46915](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46915) and [ms/TS#42384](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) for example.) You'll either need type assertions or refactoring to a supported form (like a custom type guard function, as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/WK9v8N)). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @DarrylNoakes wow thanks that works. I need to learn about type guards.

Comment: @jcalz yes that is also the solution Darryl suggested. I'm new to Typescript and if there is cleaner solution or if this is the only way I would be really interested to know.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "cleaner"? A type guard function is the standard TS way to explain to the compiler how to do narrowing that isn't built in. You could change that function to be more general-purpose, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wvaxkm) maybe, but I think the overall approach of using a type guard function is probably as "clean" as it gets (unless you can refactor so that the check happens before `doc` is created).  Anything else you do will probably either fail, or be more complicated.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance, unless you want to see something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all of the [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) behavior exhibited by TypeScript acts only on the value being checked.  That is, some operation on expression `exp1` might cause the apparent type of `exp1` to change, but it will almost never change the apparent type of some other expression `exp2`.

There are a few notable exceptions: checking the discriminant property of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) object will narrow the type of the object itself; you can sometimes [save the result of a type guard check to a `boolean` value](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants) and then a later check of that value will narrow the original expression; and you can [destructure discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) into separate variables so a check of one variable will narrow the other.

But what you're doing is not one of these exceptions.  Nothing in the language will cause a check on `x` to affect the apparent type of `doc`.  Even if they ever implement the suggestion from [microsoft/TypeScript#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) to expand property type guards to objects which are not discriminated unions, it still wouldn't give you this behavior.  In order to support this sort of thing in general, the compiler would have to perform "full counterfactual analysis" as mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#46915](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46915#issuecomment-978325778), where every possible narrowing of every expression were tracked, which would be prohibitively expensive for the compiler.  So there's not much hope of this ever working the way you want.

So what can you do instead?

---

If you don't want to refactor your code you could always [use a type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler it should treat `doc` as a `MyDoc`:

```
if (x === undefined) throw new Error();
insert(doc as MyDoc); // assert
```

Now there's no error.  But now you're responsible for verifying type safety, because the compiler can't.  There would still be no error if you performed the wrong check:

```
if (x !== undefined) throw new Error(); // oops
insert(doc as MyDoc); // assert still "works"
```

So be careful.

---

If you're more interested in getting the compiler to follow your logic, you will have to refactor to a supported narrowing method.  The most flexible way of doing this is for you to implement a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which explains exactly the narrowing you're doing to the compiler.  It still only works on the value you're checking, but at least you can express more complex typings.

For example, you can write a check to specifically see if some value is a valid `MyDoc`, perhaps like this:

```
function isMyDoc(x: any): x is MyDoc {
  return x && ("field" in x) && (typeof x.field === "string");
}
```

The compiler doesn't verify the implementation of that function, but now you can use it as much as you want elsewhere:

```
if (!isMyDoc(doc)) throw new Error();
insert(doc); // okay
```

Or, you could write a more generic guard that checks if an object has a defined property at a given key:

```
function hasDefinedProp<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T, key: K): obj is T & { [P in K]-?: Exclude<T[K], undefined> } {
  return typeof obj[key] !== "undefined"
}
```

That typing is a bit more complicated, but let's see it in action:

```
if (!hasDefinedProp(doc, "field")) throw new Error();
doc;
// { field: string | undefined } & { field: string }
insert(doc); // okay
```

That works because `doc` has been narrowed from `{ field: string | undefined }` to `{ field: string | undefined } & { field: string}` which is assignable to `MyDoc`.  The `hasDefinedProp()` type guard function has more potential use cases than `isMyDoc()`, so depending on how often this sort of check takes place in your code base, it may be more useful.

---

But, if you're interested in clean/clear code, the best approach would be to refactor so you do your check *before* you start aliasing variables:

```
const x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "abc" : undefined;
if (x === undefined) throw new Error(); // do this first
let doc = { field: x }; // then this
insert(doc); // okay
```

That sort of refactoring is not always possible for every use case, but both the compiler and human readers will more easily understand this obvious type guard flow.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKUICcAuSDeAUEkhAB4wD2OSAlsNlgGYLICyAngCIXz5HFJGNCABsAJgC4kUbJjoBzANz8AvgX6MArsHjYaFYLWAYcACjE8pHbvACU+JGv7wDMpKSQBeJKxDYAFgB0mCDAFmCm9gA8SAAMgQCsSAD8SABEIABG8GlIUtpiEELAEGLKxCIQuBa83niCwuJSHirKzq4UlYEiFPKmAFIAygDyAHKBMnLA8jSM7OY8trZtxLNIph6eW0gFRXSl9gGYFADuSCVnAKKYx5iR5UYm2Au8IFA+XIuKSAD0P0hvJ7qVaMdYeACE212xQOSCOp3OECuNyo91+-woFBgUH4dCeLwB72sX3RhKe0j0IhE6ROVAA1lA0uonKBILAWB8bABxTQgTBiPirehMDnE3iEAQNUSSClTJSqDTaXT6Qx4rDPGpWT52BxqYguYy4TY+PxBEJhCgRaJxRIpdJZHJ5HZhPYlMrtQ1IGpeBxCaXNRwPA1QToQbq9AYjcaTBSzeY1JYrQRKvQGWhQMUbKShdi2AM0InawUCTBVTSYQweABkVfWaT94lydHc9hr62w7BgEAooNIgQbAq23jSMemaWWCpB63BBczCcO-mOZwuSGut3uuOM6peE5Z4GgcEQSAAEm9OK7SgAFY4wHl8gUSowMTDMI9i4vEAdSUfy4h65M6KmqpbmYmqcosuoem4xq+AEwShOEkRIDE8RJKkGTZLk+QujC7r6q41Q8D69Rfu4gZQaG4Z9EMYwTLIsZzDuE6KoBKpIP4Z4XmI15YlEAAqJCkAwYTvBQmQAFYQLoAA0SAANKCcJYjvHSEDsD2SB8QAfKY-DEGJ4lSHxsmqewUhyXmSAGemmlILW9QANqXkY8kALoALTJFIlykPAIiaIU-EOXJrmydC+xiFpjgfkgpbYOWhgdl2GkGQ5pmuUgkLDuFbpMn+uKgqY4IcVA564TxMAvLJ9aNGI44LkuiLIuuE7EDUDx-L6tXfvR0xIAAPs6hS4dF9lSk0soKI4m74gm3ydRQdIgOwBBOAQrIHhywyZAAbvomhQCI7AAEJVM+xZkJQ1B0M+r5sEWj6ft1k3TA8TifimbFqqBljgTq9TvUgwZGj6sFmghlpIShtroQ6WFDVxDxrBsXhQjhEUNQiK5rqirVIJUhG1F1-pka0FFdD01FRnRcpxkxSMgRqJILUtK2reoQA)

Comment: Just a note about the type guard: optional properties don't work with this `hasDefinedProp` as it is. You need to remove optionality in the mapped type (`-?`). [Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mM876N)